# Como resetar um menu de seleção (selectmenu) ao alterar outro campo usando uma função?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando fazer com que um "menu de seleção" (`selectmenu`) seja resetado quando insiro um valor a mão em um campo de texto, porém apesar de já ter tentado inúmeras solução que pesquisei aqui mesmo no Stack Overflow e em outros sites, nenhuma funcionou.

Segue abaixo o meu código HTML:

```
<div>
 <label>Selecione Um Prazo Padrão:</label>
</div>
<div>
  <select name="menuPrazo" id="menuPrazo" class="menuPrazo">
    <option value="*" selected="selected">Escolha um Tipo de Prazo</option>
    <option value="1">A Vista</option>
    <option value="30">Prazo Normal</option>
    <option value="15">Prazo Estendido</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<label>Ou Informe Um Prazo Personalizado:</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" name="prazoManual" id="prazoManual" class="prazoManual" value=""></input>
</div>
```

Abaixo o código em JavaScript:

```
$(".menuPrazo").on("change", function () {
    $("#prazoManual").val("");
});

$(".prazoManual").on("change", function () {
  $('#menuPrazo').prop('selectedIndex',0);  
});
```

Além da opção contida no código acima, já tentei as seguintes opções:

```
$("select#menuPrazo").selectmenu("index", 0);
```

ou

```
$("#menuPrazo").val("");
```

ou

```
$("#menuPrazo").refresh();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qete9dp6/2/)

Answer (score 3):

Você esqueceu o ".change()" ao alterar

```
    $("#prazoManual").on("change", function () {
      $('#menuPrazo').val('*').change();
    });
```

Comment: Solução perfeita! A princípio não funcionou no meu código, apesar de ter funcionado corretamente no JSFiddle. Depois de muito quebrar a cabeça descobri que a razão de não funcionar era a ordem de carregamento das bibliotecas "Jquery", "Jquery UI" e "Jquery Mobile". Ao trocar a ordem de carregamento para essa ordem que citei, tudo funcionou corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Com o evento change em ambos fica assim:

```
<script src="js/js_1.9/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
<div>
 <label>Selecione Um Prazo Padrão:</label>
</div>
<div>
  <select name="menuPrazo" id="menuPrazo" class="menuPrazo">
    <option value="*" selected="selected">Escolha um Tipo de Prazo</option>
    <option value="1">A Vista</option>
    <option value="30">Prazo Normal</option>
    <option value="15">Prazo Estendido</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<label>Ou Informe Um Prazo Personalizado:</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" name="prazoManual" id="prazoManual" class="prazoManual" value=""></input>
</div>

<script>
    $(".menuPrazo").on("change", function () {
        $("#prazoManual").val("");
    });

    $(".prazoManual").on("change", function () {
        $('#menuPrazo option:eq(0)').attr('selected','selected');  
    });
</script>
```

claro que o correto é criar um botao para "resetar" e neste botao você implementa o evento click em fez desses seus change ai.

Comment: Tentei implementar a sua sugestão, mas não está funcionando ( http://jsfiddle.net/qete9dp6/4/ ). Alguma outra ideia?

Comment: @DanielSilva não estou conseguindo abrir o site do jsfiddle, mas testei com html que tu me passou e funcionou, só precisei colocar uma tag a mais referente ao jQuery, vou editar minha resposta e postar tudo